# puppet: Could not back up <file>: Got passed new contents for sum

Tags: puppet

I had a question I was hoping someone might have an answer to. Essentially what I'm doing is try to ensure I'm always using a fixed, slightly older version of phpunit, which I've placed in my module's file resources.

The manifest:

```
    file
    {
            "/usr/bin/phpunit":
            ensure => file,
            owner => 'root',
            group => 'root',
            mode => 0755,
            source => "puppet:///modules/php/phpunit"
    }
```

Preparation: I download the current ('wrong') version of phpunit and place it in /usr/bin.

So the first run puppet succeeds:

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for <hostname> in environment production in 3.06 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Php/File[/usr/bin/phpunit]/content: content changed '{md5}9f61f732829f4f9e3d31e56613f1a93a' to '{md}38789acbf53196e20e9b89e065cbed94'
Notice: /Stage[main]/Httpd/Service[httpd]: Triggered 'refresh' from 1 events 
Notice: Finished catalog run in 15.86 seconds
```

Then I download the current (still 'wrong') version of phpunit and place it in /usr/bin again.

This time the puppet run fails.

```
Notice: Compiled catalog for <hostname> in environment production in 2.96 seconds
Error: Could not back up /usr/bin/phpunit: Got passed new contents for sum {md5}9f61f732829f4f9e3d31e56613f1a93a
Error: Could not back up /usr/bin/phpunit: Got passed new contents for sum {md5}9f61f732829f4f9e3d31e56613f1a93a
Error: /Stage[main]/Php/File[/usr/bin/phpunit]/content: change from {md5}9f61f732829f4f9e3d31e56613f1a93a to {md5}38789acbf53196e20e9b89e065cbed94 failed: Could not back up /usr/bin/phpunit: Got passed new contents for sum {md5}9f61f732829f4f9e3d31e56613f1a93a
```

What gives? If I delete the file ( /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket/9/f/6/1/f/7/3/2/9f61f732829f4f9e3d31e56613f1a93a/ )  from my filebucket it will work again... for the next run, but not the one after that.

What am I doing wrong?

I'd appreciate any input and thanks in advance.

Comment: But is the downloaded file identical to the one that ends up in the filebucket? If so, the error does not seem to make sense. This might be a bug.

Comment: This is a bug in certain versions of puppet: https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1038

Comment: ...looks unrelated (happens when using `content` not `source` etc.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has no solution other than to upgrade since there's a bug in certain versions of puppet where files containing both UTF8 and binary characters are treated wrongly, and it results in an error message.

https://tickets.puppetlabs.com/browse/PUP-1038

The ridiculously overcomplicated solution I used as a workaround is to have a .tar file in the file resource which notifies an exec which untars and places the actual executable in the correct directory, making sure the timestamp for the latter is newer than the former.

It's far from ideal but it works in cases like mine where upgrading puppet to the most current version isn't an attractive option.

Comment: This may not be the correct answer. PUP-1038 applies to manifests which use `content =>` parameter, not the `source =>` parameter which is used in the question above. PUP-1038 says "_if you use the 'source' parameter rather than the 'content' parameter...  the manifest can be applied successfully_".

Answer (score 3):

Been having this error as well.  I solved it with a combination of two previous answers.

Firstly I had to delete /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket on the client node by running:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/puppet/clientbucket
```

Just doing this will only let it run once more.

Then I had to mark the backup => false to stop it recreating the file, missing out either step failed to solve it for me.   The accepted answer is incorrect by saying there is

> "no solution other than upgrading".

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix the same problem by removing `/var/lib/puppet/clientbucket` on the client node.

This node has been running out of disk space, so puppet has probably incorrectly stored empty files there.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, you can set `backup => false` in the file resource. This is a little unsafe, of course.

Comment: I did try backup => false, it makes no difference.